# python NLP parsing unstructured data

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, freeform

The context is that I have extracted the 'chemical contents' from different forms into free texts.

The end goal is to organize the extracted files into a structured database like this:
[final structured data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz1V2.png)

But the problems is that the extracted text files come in different formats: 
Some with the chemical & corresponding values lined up row by row (which is good)
 [good example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWuU.jpg);

Some are by column (I guess not too bad) 
 [not too good but okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W8GK.png)

Some are also like this (which is kinda headache) : 
 [headache example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihdw5.jpg)

So my question is: 
Any suggestions on how to more efficiently read and organize the extracted text into the structured database (as I have shown in the beginning), besides defining all possible templates for reading those extracted texts?

I'm really new to text processing, so any help would e greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of "smart" things that could be applied, but in general, especially for beginners; different formats need different processing. If you only have a handful of different formats, anything other than simply supporting them all is probably a waste of effort.

Comment: Okie. Thanks much!. By the way,  what are the 'smart' things you meant? I prob won't use them right now, but it would be helpful that I can get exposed to the idea so I can get to use them maybe in the future!